# pagination in jsf

Tags: jsf

I would like your comments and suggestion on this. I am doing the pagination for a page in jsf. The datatable is bound to a Backing Bean property through the "binding" attribute. I have 2 boolean variables to determine whether to render 'Prev' and 'Next' Button - which is displayed below the datatable. When either the 'Prev' or 'Next' button is clicked, In the backing bean I get the bound dataTable property and through which i get the "first" and "rows" attribute of the datatable and change accordingly. I display 5 rows in the page. Please comment and suggest if there any better ways. btw, I am not interested in any JSF Component libraries but stick to only core html render kit.

```
public String goNext()
{

    UIData htdbl = getBrowseResultsHTMLDataTable1();

    setShowPrev(true);
    //set Rows "0" or "5"
    if(getDisplayResults().size() - (htdbl.getFirst() +5)>5 )
    {
        htdbl.setRows(5);//display 5 rows
    }else if (getDisplayResults().size() - (htdbl.getFirst() +5)<=5) {
        htdbl.setRows(0);//display all rows (which are less than 5)
        setShowNext(false);
    }
    //set First
    htdbl.setFirst(htdbl.getFirst()+5);
    return "success";
}

public String goPrev()
{

    setShowNext(true);
    UIData htdbl = getBrowseResultsHTMLDataTable1();

    //set First
    htdbl.setFirst(htdbl.getFirst()-5);

    if(htdbl.getFirst()==0)
    {
        setShowPrev(false);
    }

    //set Rows - always display 5
    htdbl.setRows(5);//display 5 rows

    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Please comment and suggest if there any better ways.*

Well, that gives not much to answer on. It's at least not the way "I" would do, if you're asking for that. Long story short: [Effective datatable paging and sorting](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html). You only need Tomahawk (face it, it has its advantages). But if you're already on JSF2+Facelets instead of JSF1+JSP, then you can in fact also use `ui:repeat` and `@ViewScoped` instead of `t:dataList` and `t:saveState`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use 'Repeat' component - this is similar to dataList or dataTable component in Primefaces

```
<p:repeat id="repeatComponent" var="education" value="#{backingBean.educationList}" emptyMessage="No records found">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel for="center" value="Education Center:" />
        <br />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:outputText id="center" value="#{education.centerName}">
            </h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
 </p:repeat>
```

This is similar to for loop in java

var - this act as loop iterator
value - takes list object
emptyMessage - takes String value, will get displayed when passed list object is empty